# unable to post list item with rest api

Tags: custom-list, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-on-prem

Hi I am facing an issue while inserting Person/Group column with rest api.

I will try to explain clearly. In jquery form, i am using sp client side people picker control to save the **manager name** to Person/Group column.

In our organisation, any one can use that form to submit data to manager.

so, I have added 'Everyone' to **site members group** so that they will get contribute permission for the list.

Here the issue i am facing is, user id is not getting created automatically for the users that I am able to search in people picker. if i enter manually the user to site and submitting the form everything is working fine.

but there are 'n' number of managers which i can not add everyone to site.

Is there any resolution for my issue?

[image: captured before adding user into site groups..]

after adding the user into group, I am able to get user id, which i am using for rest api post. glad for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can do ensure user on client side people peoplePickerUserResolved function.
What it will do is it will add the user in you SharePoint site(User Information List)
Code block is

```
var initializePeoplePicker = function (ScriptFunction,peoplePickerElementId) {
    var schema = {};
    schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';
    schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;
    schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;
    schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = truw
    schema['OnUserResolvedClientScript']= ScriptFunction;
    schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;
    schema['Width'] = '280px';
    SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(peoplePickerElementId, null, schema);
 }


function peoplePickerUserResolved(peoplePickerElementId, userKey) {
            if(userKey.length>0){
              var userIndex = (userKey.length-1);
              var data = {              
                  logonName: userKey[userIndex].Key
               };
    addUserToSite(data).then(function(data){},function(data){});    
}

}

initializePeoplePicker(peoplePickerUserResolved,peoplePickerElementId);

var addUserToSite = function(data) {
        var RestUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/web/ensureuser";          
        return $.ajax({
                    url:RestUrl,
                    type:"POST",
                    headers: {
                        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                    },
                    data: JSON.stringify( data )
                });
};
```

Comment: This code is working awesome :) you are life saver for my production issue. I will definitely share this to my frnds who are in need :).. thanks a lot for your valuble inputs

Comment: Welcome , this is how we learn (by making mistakes)...